# Categories of categories where large objects are colimits over small objects

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to find out if we can find large categories like GROUP and HILB as colimits over diagrams of compact objects.  Is there a treatment of category of categories that have large objects (categories) that are colimits over small objects (categories)?

Comment: Well, any group/Hilbert space/category  is a colimit of its finitely generated subgroups/subspaces/subcategories.

Comment: Hi,  I am now wondering about a host category for your suggestion.  That is, what kind of category has, as objects, large categories like Hilb and Group, as well as all their finitely generated subcategories?  Also, do you have a reference for your stated theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are interested in the notion of a [locally presentable category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+presentable+category).

Comment: Hi,  according to [this definition](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+presentable+category), a locally presentable category would have only small objects.  I am deducing from this that any locally presentable category of categories can only have small categories as objects.

Comment: There are various hierarchies of smallness.